# How to calculate the spending multiplier from a given set of equations?

Tags: macroeconomics, general-equilibrium

So i have this question:[image]

I go along and get 
[image]

Then i need to calculate the effect on the optimal output is G increases by 80:[image]

And on the answer sheet it states that the spending multiplier is:

[image]

From my knowledge i know that 
[image]

Now how come that the spending multiplier is 1/0.4? Where are they getting the 0.4, which should be 1-c1-d1 from the original equations?

A friend told me that the 1/0.4 is derived from 1/1-c1(1-t)

then 1/1-0.8(0.75)= 1/0.4. He said that since there is no d1 in the equations ( in the investment equation) we don't use it.

Can somebody explain the meaning behind this 1/0.4) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your friend is right. If you look at the initial investment equation, and comparing it to your definition, you have:
$$I=900+(0)Y-50i$$
So $d_{1}=0$ and $c_{1}=0.8(0.75)$ and thats why you get the spending multiplier as $\frac{1}{0.4}$

Comment: but wouldn't c1 just be 0.8 and not 0.8 times 0.75?

Comment: $C=0.8(1-t)Y$ where $t$ is exogenously given. Further, if you look at your IS curve you derive, $c_1$ is that chunk that appears before $Y$. I believe it isn’t just the $0.8$

Comment: what does t being exogenous imply?? i didnt quite get it

Comment: It just means that it is computed **outside** of the model and should be taken as given. Its an assumption that simplifies the model. It is like assuming government expenditures, $G=800$ so it is easier to compute. Im sure you could dig deep into where $t$ comes from in reality.